# Azure Front Door, App Service access restrictions and AD authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-front-door

`Hey guys,

I am using Azure Front Door, an app service / web app which is authenticated with Azure AD. I seem to be running in to some problems.

I have a custom domain mapped - will use an example to demonstrate.

mydomain.com :  The custom domain
gs.mydomain.com : the Azure Front Door front end url
gsbe.mydomain.com :`` the app service custom domain

I have an access restriction applied to the app service to only allow/filter to allow requests from the front door ID. When I test using the front door frontend url, I am prompted for to authenticate but as soon as authentication takes place, I am greeted with a 403.

It doesnt look like the redirect URL is in scope for the access restrictions, but if I add the front door URL (and the azure auth path) in the redirect URL in AD, it still doesnt work.

I have read about making sure that the backend host header is left blank, but even when I do that it doesn't seem to pass the front door URL as the header so I am not sure what is going on.

I know this is quite a vague description so please ask away to get more information - but could really do with some help here. '

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Active Directory
2. Open your App Registration
3. Add you custom Front Door domain name in the Redirect URLs
4. Make sure you add the sign-in endpoint if required, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization#identity-providers)

Also make sure you have the appropriate Token mechanism selected, and the App key generated.

[image]